# SVN "No module named Numpy "

Tags: python, module

I submitted my python file to school's SVN, then I run the file. On the webpage, it returns me the following errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathfinder.py", line 428, in 
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy

I think what might happen is that, I have Numpy installed on my computer, but the webpage does not have Numpy. When I upload my python file, I only upload the file without uploading modules. How do I solve this problem?

Thank you !!

Comment: Sorry but there isn't much you can do. You should either ask your school to install it on their machines or switch to something else.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really the kind of question that Stack Overflow can help with.